# Highcharts: how display tooltip, when point = null?

Tags: highcharts

When we hover on may [In example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-connectnulls-true/), we don't see `tooltip` for this month, because data is null. Can I set the settings to see the tooltip when data is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as far as I know there is no generic option for that since highcharts ignores null values from showing.

On the other hand, we can replace the `null` points with "fake" ones, that have an average value between the 2 closest points (this will cause the chart flow remain the same), and with a custom property `isNull` which can be used as a flag later.

After doing that, we can use a `formatter` function for the tooltip, and manipulate the tooltip the way we want, for example displaying only the series name when a point `isNull`.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'The line is connected from April to Juni, despite the null value in May'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                connectNulls: true
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function(){
                if(this.point.isNull == undefined)
                    return this.series.name+"<br>"+"<b>value:</b>"+this.y;
                return this.series.name;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [null, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, null, 176.0, 135.6, null, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]

    }, function(chart){
        var series = chart.series[0];
        var data = series.data;
        $.each(data,function(i){
            var point = data[i];
            var prevPoint = data[i-1] != undefined ? data[i-1].y : 0;
            var nextPoint = data[i+1] != undefined ? data[i+1].y : 0;
            if(point.y == null){
                series.addPoint({x:point.x,y:(prevPoint+nextPoint)/2, isNull:true});
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zb5ksxtc/1/

I hope this is what you meant.

**UPDATE**
We can also do something not less hacky... (I guess a little hacking could work fine in this unusuall case)

What I did here was creating a "fake" scatter series, with points located where null values from the real series (used same average logic).
The series has hidden markers, and has a unique name.

After that, I used a `shared` tooltip and a `formatter` to display the right tooltip.
I used the `name` attribute to determine what series is focused:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'The line is connected from April to Juni, despite the null value in May'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                connectNulls: true,

            },
        },
        tooltip: {
             shared:true,

            formatter: function(){
                var points = this.points;
                var seriesName = points[0].series.name;
                if(seriesName == 'fake')
                    return "Null tooltip";
                return seriesName+"<br>value: <b>"+this.y+"</b>";
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type:'areaspline',
            data: [null, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, null, 176.0, 135.6, null, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        },
                 {
                     type:'spline',
                     lineWidth:0,
                     name:'fake',
                     showInLegend:false,
                     marker:{
                         symbol:'circle',
                         radius:0,
                     }
                 }
           ]

    }, function(chart){
        var series = chart.series[0];
        var fake_series = chart.series[1];
        $.each(series.data, function(i){
            var point = this;
            var nextPoint = series.data[i+1] != undefined ? series.data[i+1].y : 0;
            var prevPoint = series.data[i-1] != undefined ? series.data[i-1].y : 0;
            if(series.data[i].y == null)
                fake_series.addPoint([series.data[i].x, (nextPoint+prevPoint)/2]);
        });
    });
});
```

and the fiddle ofcourse: http://jsfiddle.net/zb5ksxtc/8/

Comment: You have understood correctly, but this implementation is incorrect. As areaspline we have a very ugly not smoothed line.

Comment: It doesn't look so bad in above demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zb5ksxtc/7/ Answer is correct, null points are just ignored, not rendered at all, so there is no tooltip for that points.

Comment: I edited the post, hopefuly this solution will fit more

Comment: Yes it work correct! ) last solution don't work correct, when multiple values(null) successively - the line was curved. This solution is excellent, thank you!