# Highchart - Show tooltip when hovering on missing space

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line chart with null values as shown in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovpc4azj/2/)

Here is the code for binding chart:

```
var currChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    yAxis: [{title: { text: 'Cost' } } ],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, null, 69658, 0, null, 137133, 154175]
    }],
});
```

In above example, when I hover over the points it displays `tooltip`. I want the same `tooltip` to be displayed when there is a **gap** between to datapoints. Here for Year 2012 and 2015, it should display tooltip with value 'N/A'.

I don't find any solution for this.

Comment: There would probably have to be something there for it to work, so I’m not sure that’s possible with this framework.

Comment: @Deep3015 : This stickyTracking doent work when I mouse hover on null points

Comment: How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/ovpc4azj/35/ ?  Losely based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015830/highcharts-how-display-tooltip-when-point-null

Comment: Forgot to set `type: scatter` on the added series, in case there are several nulls in a row.

Comment: @ewolden: Isn't it possible without adding fake series ?

Comment: I don't think so, because having a point as null means it is not drawn, therefore highcharts have no tooltip for that position. You could of course set the point to some random value and do lots of trickery with hiding it, but I think that would be more elaborate than having a fake series.